# Ionic 4 FAB list change content dynamically

Tags: angular, user-interface, ionic-framework

I am learning ionic 4, and have problem with dynamically changing [fab list](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab-list) contents when fab list is opened.

I am trying to achieve that after selecting main fab tha user will see list of buttons that will change over time. Below is example - `srv.getProblems()` will return last 5 problems, which will change over time.

```
  <ion-fab vertical="top" horizontal="end" *ngIf="srv.getProblems().length>0">
    <ion-fab-button color="danger">Problems</ion-fab-button>
    <ion-fab-list side="bottom">
      <ion-fab-button color="danger" *ngFor="let p of srv.getProblems()"> 
         {{p.name}}
      </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>
```

and the `srv.getProblems` is like:

```
return this.problems.filter((item, index) => index < 5 );
```

Where `this.problems` are updated from somwhere else.

Current result is that when result of srv.getProblems() changes, buttons that are new to list are added to DOM but are not visible. When I hide and reopen fab list I can see them correctly.

How can I change it to show correctly dynamically changed buttons?

Comment: There is not enough information. Could you please show **how you change list of problems**?

Comment: I added clarification, hope that this is enough. I could not find any mockup from Ionic with current version to show example here.

Comment: If you say that they **are added to DOM** it means that **it's not a problem with angular or it's change detection**, i think that it's something **connected with <ion-fab>**, unfortunately i didn't work with ionic but you can check in browser **why** these buttons are **not visible** (i mean because **of what specific style applied to them, and from where**). Also try to add `[show]=true` to your buttons, just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Amir Arbabian suggested, I checked what was missing in invisible buttons = it was `fab-button-show` class. I added it manually to templase like this:

`<ion-fab-button class="fab-button-show" color="danger" *ngFor="let p of srv.getProblems()">`

and it looks like it is working correctly now. I think this is a bug, though and I will try to report it.